# How to Use Twig + Timber with Multiple Loops based on Meta Key Value

Tags: templates

So, I've got a custom field (meta_key) 'premium' with some posts (meta_value) set to '1'.

I would like to display all of the premium posts above the the others. I imagine this would be done using multiple loops as demonstrated within the codex.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Multiple Loops

```
<?php

// The Query
$query1 = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
    $query1->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}

/* Restore original Post Data 
 * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
 * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset with 
 * wp_reset_query(). We just need to set the post data back up with
 * wp_reset_postdata().
 */
wp_reset_postdata();


/* The 2nd Query (without global var) */
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The 2nd Loop
while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    $query2->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $query2->post->ID ) . '</li>';
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

I don't know how to achieve this using Twig, and I'm struggling to find much discussion on the templating language. This is what I have in archive-agency.php

global $wp_query;

```
$premium_args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array(
    'meta_key' => 'premium-franchisor',
    'meta_value' => '1',
) );

query_posts( $premium_args );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $premium_args );

echo View::render( 'archive-agency.twig', array(
    'wp_query'       => $wp_query,
    'posts'          => $wp_query->posts,
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
) );
```

But because of the (M?)VC pattern of separating the data from the template, I can't make a second query without it wanting to render the entire view, which makes things, awkwardly appear after the footer.

Is there a better way to approach this when using Twig?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might not need multiple loops to get your data into your template.

As I understood it, it’s a matter of sorting. You want to sort your posts so that posts with `premium-franchisor` set to 1 appear first. You can already do this using WP_Query. This is how your arguments array could look like:

```php
$args = array(
    // Get all posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    // Order by meta value first, then order by post date
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'DESC'
    ),
    // Select meta key which will be used for meta_value_num in orderby
    'meta_key' => 'premium-franchisor',
);
```

Concluding from the title of your question I guess that you want to use Timber together with Twig to bring your data into your template.

This is how you could do that:

```php
<?php

$context = Timber::get_context();

$args = array(
    // Get all posts
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    // Order by meta value first, then order by post date
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
        'date' => 'DESC'
    ),
    // Select meta key which will be used for meta_value_num in orderby
    'meta_key' => 'premium-franchisor',
);

$posts = Timber::get_posts( $args );

$context['posts'] = $posts;

Timber::render( 'archive-agency.twig', $context );
```

In Timber you use a context that you fill with the data you want to hand over to your template. To set up all the basic data Timber needs, we use `get_context()` at the beginning. We then use `Timber::get_posts()` to basically do a normal WP_Query with our customized args. Getting your post through Timber will make it easier to access post properties in your template.

You could display your posts like this:

```
<div class="post-preview">
    <a href="{{ post.permalink }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    <span class="post-date">{{ post.date }}</span>
    {% if attribute( post, 'premium-franchisor') %}This is a premium post.{% endif %}
</div>
```

See, `post.permalink` or `post.title` are not properties you get when you run a normal WP_Query, but only if you query through Timber. [Here you’ll find a list](https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/TimberPost#definitions) with methods and properties that you can use.

### Using multiple loops in Timber

Since you asked how to do multiple loops, I will also show you an example of how you could achieve the same result you tried:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

// Get all premium_posts
$premium_args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'premium-franchisor',
    'meta_value' => '1',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$premium_posts = Timber::get_posts( $premium_args );

// Get all other posts
$my_other_args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'premium-franchisor',
    'meta_value' => '0',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$my_other_posts = Timber::get_posts( $my_other_args );

// Merge the two post arrays into one and assign it to context
$posts = array_merge( $premium_posts, $my_other_posts );
$context['posts'] = $posts;

Timber::render( 'index.twig', $context );
```

When you get your posts through Timber, you don’t get an object that you have to loop over to get to your data, but you get a simple array of posts to work with. You can edit, extend, sort or in your example: merge them very easily.

### A small remark on premium-franchisor

In your meta key `premium-franchisor` you used a hyphen. I’d advise you to use an underscore instead of a hyphen because often, it’s easier to access a property. E.g. you wouldn’t have to use

```
{% if attribute(post, 'premium-franchisor') %}{% endif %}
```

But could just use

```
{% if post.premium_franchisor %}{% endif %}
```

Even if this is a very late answer, I hope this will help you or others get going with Timber and Twig.